# cPickle error, writing to file results in u1conflict

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using cPickle to save some data to a file.

```
save_data = open('data/mapdata.bullet', 'wb')
save_data.write(pickle.dumps(data))
save_data.close()
os._exit(1)
```

The data consists of lists and dicts and various other stuff which takes few seconds to generate, and I want to simply have it precompiled so that debugging other parts of my code is faster when running the python script. But now, for some reason it saves the file as mapdata.bullet.u1conflict and I can't load it. Any clues as to what the reason for this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.u1conflict` are Ubuntu One conflict files, your problem is not related to cPickle. Perhaps you have another, incompatible, version of the file stored in your account on the U1 cloud: try deleting it.

Comment: Yeah.. I discovered it right after posting, but I'm not allowed to delete my question.

Comment: You can't because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question). Anyway, consider marking an answer as accepted, so that this question gets removed from the "unanswered" section.

Answer (score 1):

The `.u1conflict` extension is added by Ubuntu One, not `pickle` or `python`.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17193/u1conflict-suffix-gets-apended-to-files-while-using-ubuntu-one) explains it well.